# DynamicLink class not found in 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.6'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

Colleagues, I am trying to implement DynamicLinks in my Android App however after adding

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.6'

to my app gradle file, the package com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks cannot be resolved.

In the Firebase example on github there is package that does not exist (11.0.0)
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/dynamiclinks/app/build.gradle

Even on that project if I clone it and replace 11.0.0. with the latest 10.2.6 the class is not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your build cannot resolve, `com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.0`, you need to use the SDK Manager to download the latest Google Repository (or Google Play Services-- can't remember which).

Comment: Thanks! that was it, sorry for not replying earlier.

Comment: worked for me too thanks